# 'Syntax error, unexpected token =' in js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I am getting this error in chrome while mozilla is handling good. I am getting this error to a function which is like this

```
function abc( xyz = false){ "My logic" }
```

Error is pointing to '=' operator. please help with this.

Comment: No default argument as of ES5, `function abc( xyz){ xyz = xyz || false;  "My logic" }`

Comment: What's going on with `xyz = false`? The compiler is expecting an identifier there, but is getting an assignment.

Comment: Mozilla supports default parameters while Chrome is not yet.

Comment: You can check here for es6 [compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). See "default function parameters":

Comment: jesus... how people are misusing their power of reputation...!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a standard of ***ECMASCRIPT version 6*** and it's called [Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters). So it might be not available in your chrome version while FF has.

You can achieve the same by two ways:

```
function abc( xyz ){ "My logic" }

var pVal = mightbe || false;
abc(pVal); //<---- now pass it here;
```

or:

```
function abc( xyz ){ 
    // before processing anything you can do this
    var o = xyz || false; // if there is any value in the xyz then that will
                          // be assigned otherwise false will be the default value.
    "My logic" 
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with destructuring, it's different thing.

Comment: Although you're right about being an ES6 standard, the name is Default Parameters. Destructuring assignment is only a subset of it, e.g: `function f([x, y] = [1, 2], {z: z} = {z: 3}) {`.

Answer (score 0):

This is ES6 syntax, most browsers only support very few ES6 features, you can check from here: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ (In your example you used default function parameters)

If you want to write ES6 syntax (which is quite appealing in many ways), you can use some code transpiling tool like babel: https://babeljs.io/